# Unable to connect play 2.5 application with MYSQL - JPA Issue

Tags: mysql, jpa, jdbc, playframework

Application.conf is like this

```
db {
  default.jndiName=DefaultDS
  default.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  default.url =  "jdbc:mysql://sql6.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/sql6157743" 
  default.username = sql6157743
  default.password = "smEkGrF1Kr"
}
```

When I try to create 
EntityManager em = play.db.JPA.em() it givers error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No EntityManager found in the context. Try
>   to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional

And when I annotate it with @Transactional it gives error

> [CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to remove
>   the EntityManager, but none was set.]

And If I add **jpa.default=applicationPersistenceUnit** line in **Application.conf** file it give error

> [CompletionException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to
>   provision, see the following errors:
>
> 1) Error injecting constructor,
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named applicationPersistenceUnit   at
>   play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.(DefaultJPAApi.java:39)
>   at
>   play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.class(DefaultJPAApi.java:34) 
>   while locating play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider   while
>   locating play.db.jpa.JPAApi
>       for parameter 0 at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.(TransactionalAction.java:20)
>   while locating play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction
>
> 1 error]

I tried to create Entity  Manager from Entity Manager Factory and Persistence Unit but I don't have any persistence unit name even persistence.xml file in my project. I tried to create persistence.xml using Persistence Tools but failed

```
EntityManagerFactory factory;
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("No persistence unit name I have");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

Any solution? I just need to save and query in two tables at MYSQL. Any method to do this?

Comment: Is your `persistence.xml` correctly configured?

Comment: @gpgekko I mentioned in post, I don't have any persistence.xml file in my project. Can't I work without persistence.xml file? Any alternate?

Comment: You can, but you can't mix convenience integration with custom needs. If you want to provide something in a none-standard way, you'll have to do none-standard things. You'd probably want to implement a custom [JPAConfig](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java-jpa/src/main/java/play/db/jpa/JPAConfig.java) and bind that to the interface. Then you can create your stuff on time in there.